# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined in custom js admin panel

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, modal-popup

I loaded custom js in head section of **grid ui component** in order to open a model dialog box when i click a button.

```
require([
"jquery",
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($, modal){

var options = {
    type: 'popup',
    responsive: true,
    innerScroll: true,
    title: 'Title',
    buttons: [{
        text: $.mage.__('Proceed'),
        class: '',
        click: function () {
            /* some stuff */
            this.closeModal();
        }
    }]
};
var popup = modal(options,$('#popup-modal'));

$("#print").click(function(){       
....
....}});
```

Its throw an following error when page load

**jquery.js:3762 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined**

can any one suggest please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

add this code you will resolve the problem

```
if ($("#popup-modal").length != 0) {

var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal')); 

jQuery('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');

}
```